# jquery firing mouse out for ul when navigating between li

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, mouse

I have an html page that has a list

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then some jquery code to fire an event on mouse out of the list

```
$('#mylist').mouseout(function(evt) {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

The problem is that when I move the mouse between item1 and item2 (vertically starting at item1 and moving down to item2), the mouse out fires (and $this is referencing the ul). Why would the ul be firing an event even though I don't think I've left the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you'll want to use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) / [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of mouseover / mouseout.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to "event bubbling" of JavaScript.  Events of li are bubbled up to ul. Read more about this here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

This is may not be a direct answer to the question, but I believe it something any JS developer should know.

Comment: At first I thought it might be related to that (and it still might be), but the weird thing is that the inner element (the `li` in this case) was not firing an event. I was only seeing the event from the outer element (the `ul`)

Comment: You say $this refers to ul, which is fine since it is the ul handling the event. Can you please check what event.target points to? I believe it should point to the li element. Thanks for your time. :-)

Comment: The target is the link tag `<a>`

Comment: Cool, so it is bubbling, (did not notice the a earlier), anyway mousenter should work for you,  check jQuery doc it specifically say mousenter will not bubble,  but be careful, this is not a native browser event, it proprietary to IE but replicated by jQuery. It might cause undesired behavior if mouse is moved at crazy speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you are binding mouseout to a , mouseovering its children (

) will trigger a mouseout (if I am correct). As Aesthete mentioned, wrapping it with a div and bind mouseover to that div is more simple and straight forward to do.